# How to arrange a 2 file savesystem to prevent data loss?

Tags: c

Specifically, I would like to know which functions I need and what would be the most efficient order of operations. (I know about fopen()+fwrite() and rename() for now)

a) Rename file.txt to file_old.txt - save (overwrite) file.txt
b) Save (overwrite) old file_old.txt - save (overwrite) file.txt
c) ???

Also, should the old file be hidden or visible or deleted?

Looking for a safe and efficient C99 solution with using only the standard library functions

Comment: Two files will be out of sync. You can use RAID to prevent data loss, or keep a log file in addition to your normal files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip your proposed step 1.

Just write to a new randomly named file (e.g. `file.txt.tmp.XXXXX`), then call [`rename`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) to have that file replace `file.txt`.

On POSIXes, atomicity is guaranteed:

> If `newpath` already exists, it will be atomically replaced, so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access `newpath` will find it missing.

`MoveFileEx(src, dst, MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING)` is the equivalent Windows call.

Comment: It's important to remember that atomicity is only guaranteed if the source and destination path are on the **same** filesystem. (POSIX)